# Eslint warning for dangerous use of "as"

Tags: typescript, eslint

I could see that the following code did not trigger any errors or warnings:

```
type myType = {a:number,b:number}
const myObject = {a:1} as myType
```

We just had an issue where using "as" caused a production bug, which made me think that there might be an eslint rule that should disallow this. Do you know any such rule?

Comment: If the usage of "as" did create a production bug, then the issue is not the usage of "as". The issue is the lack of tests. It is not possible that a production bug happens because of a mistype if there is a test suite that covers 100% of the code and 100% of the edge cases. Blaming the "as" token is being in denial, with all due respect, and won't improve the quality of your prodcts in the future.

Comment: Have anybody ever been able to say they 100 % test coverage and 100% coverage of all edge cases for a frontend app?

Comment: Yes. Obviously because they actually tried to reach that goal. I have the feeling you didn't try but I may be wrong. In the current case, instead of forbidding a language construct, you could implement a test that match the context of the bug, and fix the code accordingly so that the test pass. This way you would have guaranteed that this exact situation will never happen again, whatever the way the code is written.

Comment: @EricMORAND I don't think "write more tests" is a good approach here. The point of Typescript is to ensure correctness by evaluating static types. `as` keyword breaks that here. One could easily argue that Typescript isn't needed at all if one has 100% test coverage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) can really be dangerous when used carelessly. No, [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) does not ship a rule to completely forbid type assertion out of the box. So you'll have to use a custom plugin such as

[eslint-plugin-no-type-assertion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-no-type-assertion)

> Disallow type assertions in TypeScript code. The rule will forbid both as operator and the angle-bracketed syntax, unless used for const assertions or with the unknown type. The rule also forbids non-null assertions.

---

There are other packages though that offer options to disallow type assertion:

- [typescript-eslint](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/): You can enable the [consistent-type-assertions](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/consistent-type-assertions/) rule and set `assertionStyle` to `"never"`:

> This option defines the expected assertion style. Valid values for assertionStyle are:
> as will enforce that you always use ... as foo.
> angle-bracket will enforce that you always use ...
> never will enforce that you do not do any type assertions.

- [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/): You can enable the [no-object-literal-type-assertion](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-object-literal-type-assertion/) rule:

> Forbids an object literal to appear in a type assertion expression. Casting to any or to unknown is still allowed.

However, I'm not sure if it's a good idea to completely disallow type assertion. There are valid use cases where you really need it. You're [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is just a severe programmer mistake where basic type security is being ignored.

---

P. S. [`type` alias names](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) should be spelled with a Capital by convention (e. g. `type MyType = ...`)

Comment: "Neither ESLint nor typescript-eslint ship a rule to completely forbid type assertion out of the box" that isn't true - typescript-eslint ships consistent-type-assertions, which has an option that can be set to "never" to flag any use of them.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! I never noticed that. Updated my answer.